# How to add Multiple Searches in AWK command

Tags: shell, shell-script, rhel, scripting, awk

Im trying to search for the files Created in June,July and August months. I used this method

```
ls -lrth|awk '/[Jun][Jul][Aug]/ {print}'
```

but it ain't working.

Comment: For the record, the `[...]` construct matches a single character, which can be any one of the characters between the brackets.  So your expression matches `JJA`  or `Jug` (`J` from `[Jun]`, `u` from `[Jul]`, and `g` from `[Aug]`) but not the month abbreviations you were hoping to match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can match on multiple patterns like so:

```
awk '/Jun/ || /July/ || /Aug/' <(ls -lrh)
```

This returns all matches for either Jun, July, or Aug.
You don't require the `print` statement as that is `awk`'s default action.

Comment: awk understands extended regexps, so for a pattern as simple as that you could write it as `awk '/Jun|Jul|Aug/'` or `awk '/Ju[nl]|Aug/'`

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, it is a very bad idea to [parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A better way to do what you want is

```
stat -c "%n %y" * | grep 2013-0[678]
```

Alternatively, check only the last field to protect against the unlikely case where the file name itself is a date:

```
stat -c "%n %y" *| awk '$NF ~ /2013-0[678]/'
```

From `man stat`:

```
   -c  --format=FORMAT
          use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output  a  new‐
          line after each use of FORMAT

   %y     time of last modification, human-readable
   %n     file name
```

Comment: It is also a good example. I never checked STAT before. thanks for great info

Comment: Maybe change to ...`| awk '$NF ~ /2013-0[678]/'` to only check the last output field, in the (unlikely?) even that a file's *name* matches the regex even when the date doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

`ls` is a command to display information about files in a human readable. [Do not use it in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

The command to find files in a directory tree matching certain criteria is [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find). If you have GNU find (i.e. non-embedded Linux or Cygwin) or FreeBSD find (i.e. FreeBSD or OSX), you can use `-newermt` to match files that were last modified after a certain date.

```
find . -newermt '1 June' ! -newermt '1 September' -print
```

Add a year if you want to match files in a specific year, rather than the calendar year when the script runs.

If your find implementation doesn't have `-newermt`, you'll have to make do with `-newer`, which compares the date of the file that `find` found with a fixed file. use `touch` to create temporary files with the date that you want to use as a boundary.

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)
touch -d 201306010000 "$dir/from"
touch -d 201309010000 "$dir/to"
find . -newer "$dir/from" ! -newer "$dir/to" -print
rm -r "$dir"
```