# Extract all lines from a word to another with my match in between

Tags: text-processing, grep, cygwin

I have a file with the following structure:

```
[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution
```

This structure is repeated several times, like a dictionary. Each definition starts with `[Term]` and it's separated from the following by an empty newline; not every definition ends with a line starting with `is_a`.
I want to grep some terms and retrieve the whole definition, so from `[Term]` to the empty newline; i.e., the structure example shown before could be the result of `grep -i "mitochondria" myfile`. How do I do it? The number of lines of each definition is not fixed, and the match could be at any point of the definition.

I'm not sure that `grep` is the right tool to do it; the thing is that I want to match several words at once, so I started using `grep -i -e "match" -e "someothermatch"`. Is there some `regex` that does the trick?

I work with Cygwin in a Windows environment, and apparently it supports PCRE.

Comment: can you provide more number of structure and the expected output

Comment: As per your title, i understood that, you need something like this...

awk '/start_pattern/,/end_pattern/' filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description (emphasis mine):

> Each definition starts with `[*Term*]` and
>   **it's separated from the following by an empty newline**

Awk, when called with a null RS (`RS=''`) splits a file on empty lines.
It is also capable of selecting based on strings:

```
$ var="someothermatch"
$ awk -v RS='' -v var="$var" '$0~var{print}' infile
```

Should work to get the *whole paragraph* that match.

From awk manual:

> If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string,  the  newline character always acts as a field separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have.

Comment: Thank you, RS is what I was looking for! Actually I wanted to find more th than one match, but following http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92815/how-to-add-multiple-searches-in-awk-command I modified your command in this way:
`awk -v RS='' '/match|anothermatch|thirdmatch/ {print}'`
with no actual need of a variable.